# Counting down a number in the title using php/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, title, countdowntimer, rpg

I need to automatically count down a php variable -1 every 5 seconds displayed in the title oft the page and automatically update eg. title: '23/30 Auto Battles Remaining'.

Is this possible to do in php/jquery?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code to get helped

Comment: What have you tries so far?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP - not possible
In JS (you can't do it in `*.js` file)

```
var counter = <?php echo $currentGames; ?>,
counterTimer,
totalGames = <?php echo $totalGames; ?>;

counterTimer = setInterval(reCounter(), 5000);

function reCounter() {
    window.title = counter + '/' + totalGames + ' Auto Battles Remaining';

    if (counter <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counterTimer);
    }
    counter--;
}
```

Comment: The number will not always be 30, I selected the "30" from a field in the db. current battles/total battles, part I was having trouble with is getting the php int he title with js :/

Comment: @sk1p so your numbers comes from PHP side and you want to check it every 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes, just needs to select the number from php side and minus by 1 every 5 seconds and automatically refresh in the page title/tab. Thank you for your help so far I appreciate it.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work :/